# "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pipeline' found" when running declarative JenkinsFile from SCM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a very simple Jenkinsfile written in the declarative style:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
               echo "hello" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When we run it directly from within our pipeline job (i.e. the script isn't loaded from SCM) in Jenkins (v.2.107.0) it works as expected.  But when we load the same script from SCM (git on VSTS) we get the following error:

```
Started by user admin
Replayed #50
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, container, containerLog, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext, git, httpRequest, input, isUnix, junit, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, parallel, podTemplate, powershell, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, timeout, tool, unarchive, unstash, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitForQualityGate, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, allOf, always, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, batchFile, booleanParam, branch, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildingTag, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changeRequest, changelog, changeset, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, clock, cloud, command, configMapVolume, containerEnvVar, containerLivenessProbe, containerTemplate, credentials, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, dependencyCheckAnalyzer, dependencyCheckPublisher, dependencyCheckUpdateOnly, dependencyTrackPublisher, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, docker, dockerCert, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, durabilityHint, emptyDirVolume, emptyDirWorkspaceVolume, envVar, envVars, environment, equals, expression, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, git, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hostPathVolume, hostPathWorkspaceVolume, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, installSource, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, kubernetes, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, myView, newContainerPerStage, nfsVolume, nfsWorkspaceVolume, node, nodeProperties, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, persistentVolumeClaim, persistentVolumeClaimWorkspaceVolume, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, podAnnotation, podEnvVar, pollSCM, portMapping, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, remotingCLI, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApprovalLink, search, secretEnvVar, secretVolume, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, sshUserPrivateKey, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, tag, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, withSonarQubeEnv, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor227.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

We know the script is loading fine (the path is correct and the Git checkout works). The error comes from the fact that Jenkins is trying to use the JobDSL plugin to run the script.  We don't want that to happen.

Comment: Maybe it is an encoding problem. Look into the file with a hex Editor if there is a not printable character at the beginning of the file

Comment: @Jens let's move your comment into answers, please. It helps me a lot, and probably should be much more visible and upvoted.Rider on windows created .jf file in UTF-8 BOM with "\ufeff" not printable character, which caused error described in topic.

Answer (score 20):

I am pretty sure you haven't installed [workflow-aggregator](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator) plugin. The `pipeline` DSL should get recognized once this plugin or one of those other plugins that dependens on it is installed.

Comment: After the install restart jenkins,