# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pipeline'

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a Pipeline in Jenkins and I am trying to run Jenkinsfile that's defined in my project.

```
pipeline{

   agent any
   
   stages{

       stage('Build application'){
           steps{
              echo 'Building the application ..'
           }
       }
       
       stage('Test application'){
           steps{
              echo 'Testing the application ..'
           }
       }
   
       stage('Deploy application'){
           steps{
              echo 'Deploying the application ..'
           }
       }
   
   }

}
```

When I am trying to Build my project I am getting this exception :

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pipeline' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, error, fileExists, getContext, git, input, isUnix, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, parallel, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, retry, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, tool, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withContext, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, batchFile, booleanParam, buildButton, buildDiscarder, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, choice, choiceParam, clock, cloud, command, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, envVars, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, git, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, installSource, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jnlp, jobName, junit, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, myView, nodeProperties, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, run, runParam, schedule, scm, scmRetryCount, search, security, shell, slave, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, viewsTabBar, weather, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, env, params, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:149)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:48)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:324)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I checked an installed Plugins and I definitely have "Pipeline" plugin installed together with "Pipeline steps" etc etc.

My Jenkins version is 2.19.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718320/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-such-dsl-method-pipeline-found-when-running

Comment: thank you, I saw it before, it didn't help. That's why I verified Pipeline plugin being installed. Strange thing is when switch to scripting at least it's being picked up for execution